# Python Pandas - Remove Duplicates with Inverse Values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Assume `df` is like:

```
pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["banana", "apple", "grapes", "banana"],
              "col2": ["apple", "banana", "apple", "grapes"]})
col1    col2
banana  apple
apple   banana
grapes  apple
banana  grapes
```

How can we remove the inverse duplicates, that is : `banana`-`apple` and `apple`-`banana` combos ?

I tried

```
df["col_to_check"] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x), axis=1).astype(str)
idx_to_remove = df[df.duplicated(["col_to_check"])].index
```

Other recommendations ?